Safari keyboard shortcut to move to next URL link on webpage
In Safari, is there a keyboard shortcut to move to the next URL link on webpage. For example if I do a Google search that returns a full page of URL links, is there a keyboard shortcut to move the focus to the next link on the page?

From Apple documentation: Keyboard shortcuts and gestures in Safari on Mac



Action
Shortcut or gesture




Highlight the next field, pop-up menu, or clickable item (such as a link) on a webpage
Option-Tab Option-Tab also highlights buttons and other controls if Keyboard Navigation is turned on in Keyboard settings. To swap the behavior of Tab and Option-Tab, turn on “Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage” in the Advanced pane of Safari settings



Using Safari exclusively from keyboard can be achieved with extensions like Vimlike or Vimari
